# Accessing classes/models with Flask Sqlalchemy which I created through pandas.to_sql

Tags: python, pandas, flask-sqlalchemy

I am trying to develop a web app with Flask. What I am trying to do is:

1. Get data from client in the form of a table
2. Use pandas to perform calculations on each row of the table and create multiple dfs and then append them to a single df
3. Then use to_sql to upload the consolidated df to a table in postgres database using Flask SQLalchemy
   (I am fine uptil here)
4. Then I want to use Flask sqlalchemy to query and edit the table in the database.

The problem is step 4. Since I am using to_sql function to create the table within the database, the table does not have any primary key.

When I use the following code to reflect classes:

```
db.Model.metadata.reflect(db.engine)

class LeaseInfo(db.Model):
    __table__ = db.Model.metadata.tables['lease_info']

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.DISTRICT
```

I get the following error:
**sqlalchemy.exc.ArgumentError: Mapper mapped class LeaseInfo->lease_info could not assemble any primary key columns for mapped table 'lease_info'**

When I use the following code to access the classes:

```
Base = automap_base()
Base.prepare(db.engine, reflect = True)
LeaseInfo = Base.classes.lease_info
```

I get the following error: **line 212, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError(key)
AttributeError: lease_info**

I have seen suggestions which say that I define the classes first with all columns and then append with to_sql but I want to be able to do it more dynamically.

Answer (score 1):

Ended up defining classes (db.Model) within the app and then appending data to the models with pd.to_sql but would still like to know a shorter way if possible.